# Python open: Invalid argument error

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have the following two xml links, each of which I want to use as the `file` parameter to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
table1 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1103804/000110380417000040/xslForm13F_X01/Form13fInfoTable.xml'
table2 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1103804/000110380417000040/Form13fInfoTable.xml'
```

What I have tried:

- Using raw strings (`r'https:// ...`)
- Excluding `https://` in each of the path names (to get rid of the colon on a Windows system)
- Using `'r'` within `open()`, which should be unnecessary anyway because it is the default

There are a number of similar SO questions, none of which offer solutions that get rid of this error.  Although the following is seemingly innocuous I cannot get past the error.  For instance,

```
d = open(table1, 'r')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-07d32326a11e> in <module>()
----> 1 d = open(table1, 'r')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1103804/000110380417000040/xslForm13F_X01/Form13fInfoTable.xml'
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use ``open``? Since those are online resources, I would suggest you [download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22682/4349415) them and work with the returned bytes/string.

Comment: Why are you using open to open a URL?

Comment: import urllib

    urllib.urlopen('http://example.com')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the open function you want.

```
import urllib

urllib.urlopen('http://example.com') #python 2

urllib.request.urlopen('http://example.com') #python 3
```

Comment: I was following along blindly with [this](http://www.austintaylor.io/lxml/python/pandas/xml/dataframe/2016/07/08/convert-xml-to-pandas-dataframe/) walkthrough, which uses `open`.  Thanks, and in 3.x this is `urllib.request.urlopen`